# Listening to ICommandBar or ICommand OnClick event?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, extensions

I have an ArcMap extension and I'm listening to the IEditEvents.

When the OnChangeFeature, OnCreateFeature or OnDeleteFeature event is called, I want to know if it came from the "merge(Editor_Merge)" button.

Is there a way I can listen to the onClick event of the merge button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try implementing [ICustomizationFilter](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ICustomizationFilter_Interface/0023000000n6000000/).  When OnCustomizationEvent is called, check to see if it is esriCEInvokeCommand.  If it is, then you should be able to cast the object passed as an ICommandItem.  Check to see if the ICommmandItem references the Editor_Merge command (using ICommandItem.ID).  If it does, set a flag in your extension so that your eventhandler for edit events can know how to react.

Comment: Works great! thanks for the help!
I was already using a customization filter, but I didn't realize that I could catch click events!

Comment: Example in VB http://rzeckoskiengineering.blogspot.com.co/2012/06/capturing-button-clicks-in-arcobjects.html