# How to trigger a Python script from an ArcGIS Desktop "save" operation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, python-addin

Similar to the question [Run a Python Script when opening an MXD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/run-a-python-script-when-opening-an-mxd), I'm looking for a way to run a Python script that is triggered when the "Save" command/button is pressed.

I've read the [Creating a Python add-in application extension](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000018000000) help for building a Python Add-In, but I don't see an interface in the [Extension class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000019000000) that triggers upon Save, only close.

Is there something I might be overlooking?  Otherwise, what are my alternative options ***other*** than ArcObjects, which is a road I am not willing to explore for this idea?

Comment: Which save: edits or map? The only thing I can see is http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001v00000126000000

Comment: I am looking for something to work on save of MXD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something in ArcObjects that will do the job. Thanks to [This Post by Kirk Kuykendall](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/can-i-listen-to-the-icommandbar-or-icommand-onclick-event) as implemented on [This Post by Rebecca Zeckoski](http://rzeckoskiengineering.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/capturing-button-clicks-in-arcobjects.html). This is very counter-intuitive, the interface to find button clicks is [ICustomizationFilter](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0023000000n6000000), which detects when a command is about to run (any command that implements ICommand I think).

Using Visual Studio I created an ArcMap addin and selected Extension and AutoLoad, then added a class alongside which implements [ICustomizationFilter](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0023000000n6000000), using the [LockCustomization](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/LockCustomization_Method/00230000003q000000/) method of the application the class is linked to the event then call the python script by (in this case) shell() other methods are discussed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807860/execute-python-script-from-vb-net); I'm not sure if you can make an [ICommandItem](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002300000071000000) from a python add-in but that would be how I would execute custom ArcObjects code.

```
Public Class Extension1 
    Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension
    'I am not using this event'
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStartup()
        WireDocumentEvents() ' uncomment this, it is here by default'
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnShutdown()
    End Sub

    Private Sub WireDocumentEvents()
        AddHandler My.ArcMap.Events.NewDocument, AddressOf ArcMapNewDocument ' this is a default event'
        AddHandler My.ArcMap.Events.OpenDocument, AddressOf ArcMapDocumentOpen ' add this event'
    End Sub

    Private Sub ArcMapNewDocument()
        ' Wire the event here in case the user starts with a blank'
        ' map and saves... this event does not survive a file::open'
        Dim pCustFlt As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICustomizationFilter = New CustFlt
        My.ArcMap.Application.LockCustomization("myLock", pCustFlt)
    End Sub
    Private Sub ArcMapDocumentOpen()
        ' When the document is opened wire the events to it'
        ' otherwise they dissapear after a new MXD is opened.'
        Dim pCustFlt As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICustomizationFilter = New CustFlt
        My.ArcMap.Application.LockCustomization("myLock", pCustFlt)
    End Sub
End Class
Class CustFlt   ' new class to implement the filter'
    Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICustomizationFilter

    Public Function OnCustomizationEvent(custEventType As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriCustomizationEvent, eventCtx As Object) As Boolean Implements ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICustomizationFilter.OnCustomizationEvent
        ' modified from Rebecca Zeckoskis' post http://rzeckoskiengineering.blogspot.com.au/2012/06/capturing-button-clicks-in-arcobjects.html
        ' inspired by Kirk Kuykendalls' post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/can-i-listen-to-the-icommandbar-or-icommand-onclick-event

        If custEventType = ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriCustomizationEvent.esriCEInvokeCommand Then
            ' if it is a call to invoke a command then find the command
            ' that is being invoked (executed)
            Dim cmd As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem
            cmd = TryCast(eventCtx, ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem)

            ' find the name of the command, there's a whole bunch of them
            ' at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000029s000000
            ' search by tool caption to find others, you can use either the name or GUID/CLSID
            If cmd.Name = "File_Save" Then
                MsgBox("Customization Save") ' run your python here
                ' if you have a custom ArcObjects tool here you could make a new
                ' ICommandItem and execute, not sure if that works for python
                ' addins. You can call the shell with the path like this:
                Shell("c:\path\to\your\script.py", AppWinStyle.Hide, False) ' returns an integer
                ' see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807860/execute-python-script-from-vb-net
            End If
        End If

        Return False

    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet will be to create a custom button that saves your map document - `mxd.save()` - as well as whatever operations you wish.

Comment: Like a 'save with benefits' button.. that would work but I can see what he's trying to do; the best way to ensure a script is run is to not give the operator the option... with a 'special save' button, how can you ensure that the user has clicked that one and not just closed the window and hit yes on the save dialog?

Comment: That's a good suggestion if there are no other options.  But as @MichaelMiles-Stimson mentioned, the whole point is to provide a "pain free" experience that just happens behind the scenes.