# What events are fired when a feature is copy and pasted?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, events

I am trying to detect when a feature has been copied and pasted.  The [OnCreateFeature](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IEditEvents_OnCreateFeature.htm) event fires, but I cannot tell if the feature object was copy/pasted.  Is there an event or other method to differentiate pasted features from newly created features?

EDIT: Two possible approaches I've thought of, but not sure of efficacy or downsides.

1. In the OnCreateFeature event, I can read the 'new' feature's attributes, and compare them to the DefaultValue of each field.  If every value is default, it's probably a new feature and not a copied feature.
2. Get the geometry of the 'new' feature, and compare it to the geometry of every selected feature.  If there is a match, the feature is a copy/paste.

Comment: Did you try using `ICustomizationFilter` to trap when the paste command is invoked ?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/8152/59

Comment: @KirkKuykendall That's perfect! Post an answer and I'll accept.  I'm posting my solution for the sake of posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off help provided by Kirk Kuykendall, I came up with the following solution.  I wanted to post it here as a c# alternative to [this post](http://rzeckoskiengineering.blogspot.com/2012/06/capturing-button-clicks-in-arcobjects.html).  It assumes you are already listening for OnStartEditing and OnStopEditing events.

```
namespace MyAddin {
    public class MyExtensionClass : ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Extension {
        private ICustomizationFilter _filter;

        // Constructors and methods to listen for edit events here

        private void OnStartEditing() {
            _filter = new myCustomizationFilter();
            ArcMap.Application.LockCustomization("password", _filter);
        }
        private void OnStopEditing(bool save) {
            ArcMap.Application.UnlockCustomization("password");
        }
    }

    public class myCustomizationFilter : ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICustomizationFilter {
        public bool OnCustomizationEvent(esriCustomizationEvent custEventType, object eventCtx) {
            if (custEventType == esriCustomizationEvent.esriCEInvokeCommand) {
                ICommandItem cmd = eventCtx as ICommandItem;
                if (cmd.Name == "Edit_Paste") {
                    // do something here
                } else if (cmd.Name == "Edit_Copy") {
                    // do something else here
                } else if (cmd.Name == "Edit_Cut") {
                    // do something else here
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

All menu, toolbar, and command names and GUIDs can be found [here](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/8.3/?URL=/arcobjectsonline/technicaldocuments/arcmapids.htm), as well as techniques for finding references to specific command items.